# OpenSSL - Multithread environment - C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm using non-blocking sockets and OpenSSL 1.1.0 to create a simple web server.

The clients requests is handled inside 4 threads and the threads is created using C++ ( `std::thread` ).

My question is: Can we use the C++ threads to make OpenSSL thread safe for each client request?

I ask this because i have found this:

> *) OpenSSL now uses a new threading API. It is no longer necessary to
>        set locking callbacks to use OpenSSL in a multi-threaded environment. There
>        are two supported threading models: **pthreads** and **windows threads**. It is
>        also possible to configure OpenSSL at compile time for "no-threads". The
>        old threading API should no longer be used. The functions have been
>        replaced with "no-op" compatibility macros.
>        [Alessandro Ghedini, Matt Caswell]

Comment: I guess it depends on your compiler or its STL library and whether they use either pthreads or Windows threads under the covers for std::thread. And chances are they will.

Comment: Don't share OpenSSL *objects* between threads, then you'll be safe.